# el servidor no encuentra el código js, web desarrollada en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, cpanel

Subi la web a el cpanel de prueba, pero no me funciona el JS, la web la estoy desarrollando con laravel 6.
he intentado poniendo `asset()` y con `url()` pero no me ubica el archivo.

de esta manera estoy poniendo la ruta:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/service.js')}}"></script>
```

este es el error que sale:
GET https://tfxqrcjv.lucusvirtual.es/js/service.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ahi esta la url de la pagina.

muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu ruta dice `viewport.js` y tu error hace referencia a `service.js`

Comment: que pena puse otra ruta en el ejemplo, ya la corregí

Comment: En tu página de ejemplo no hay referencias a Javascript más que el de jQuery, pero creo saber cuál es el problema, prueba con `<script src="{{asset('JS/service.js')}}"></script>` (JS con mayúsculas)

Comment: Muchas gracias, de  una funciono; me podrias decir  por que es con mayúscula si la carpeta la tengo en minúscula

Comment: Buena pregunta xD me di cuenta porque el folder de tus CSS también están con mayúscula, nunca vi que Laravel cambiara los folders, quizás sea un parámetro adicional de Laravel o del servidor.

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad; había perdido mucho tiempo en ese error; esos son los errores que dueles jajaja

Comment: por los general en los localhost no es tan estricto si usas mayusculas y el archivo es minusculas o viceversa pero ya en produccion si son bastante estrictos con esta regla. una sola letra basta para que de error404

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, pues abro la consola y no veo error, además que los estilos parecen cargar bien